# MySQL using like to match specific string

Tags: mysql, string, sql-like

In my column I can have either a string like : "data+" or "data+data+data+..(undefined times)..+"
I simply need to **get the column where I have multiples data and not only one.**

I tried with

```
mycol NOT LIKE '%+'
```

But it didn't work...

Actually I don't know the data it is a string that varies : 'blabla' or 'aString' or 'whatever'

If I had in my columns

```
'jdsjpgsg+jdsjpgsg+', 'dvgff+', 'ffef+eefds+ghghgh+'
```

I want to select only

```
'jdsjpgsg+jdsjpgsg+',
'ffef+eefds+ghghgh+',
```

NOT `'dvgff+'` !

Comment: Try `mycol NOT LIKE 'data+%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to search '..xxx+..' then you should be use `xxx+%`

if you want to search '..+xxx..' then you should be use `%+xxx`

if you want to search '..++..' then you should be use `%++%`

if you want to search '..+..+..' then you should be use `%+%+%`

---

> It is what I get too and I dont want that. It is actually what i don't want to select. If I had jdsjpgsg+jdsjpgsg+ in my table I want to select it and NOT jdsjpgsg+ It is tricky...

so you can try `like '%+%+%'` to exclude just one '+'

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
    (`text` varchar(90))
;

INSERT INTO TestTable
    (`text`)
VALUES
    ('jdsjpgsg+jdsjpgsg+'),
    ('dvgff+'),
    ('ffef+eefds+ghghgh+')
;
```

---

```
select * from TestTable
where text like '%+%+%'
```

---

```
|               text |
|--------------------|
| jdsjpgsg+jdsjpgsg+ |
| ffef+eefds+ghghgh+ |
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78ed3c/1/0)

Comment: It is what I get too and I dont want that. It is actually what i don't want to select. If I had jdsjpgsg+jdsjpgsg+ in my table I want to select it and NOT jdsjpgsg+ It is tricky....

Answer (score 0):

The `%` is the wildcard character. You should be using the `%` after `data`. Try like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `mycol` NOT LIKE 'data+%'
```

The above query will filter out all the records that have any characters after `data+`.